# Windows Phone and Silverlight ListBox.ItemTemplate

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, listbox, windows-phone, itemtemplate

I have a Windows Phone 7 application with the following listbox and every item contains 2 textblocks and a HyperlinkButton.

```
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate><DataTemplate><StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock/>
                            <TextBlock/>
                            <HyperlinkButton Content="[More...]" FontSize="12"HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="30" Click="ClickEvent">
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click"<GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding GetCommand, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </HyperlinkButton>
                        </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

In the ViewModel constructor  I have the following code:

```
GetCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>{some code}); where GetCommand is a property :

public RelayCommand GetCommand { get; private set; }
```

My problem is that `GetCommand = new RelayCommand(() =>{some code});` is not executing when I press the button.

I must say that if dont place the HyperlinkButton insise the itemTemplate, everything works fine.
I use the Galasoft mvvm light tookit - http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/getstarted/ 
I appreciate any help.

Comment: Please don't ask such similar questions in such quick sucession.  Just edit your original question with extra detail.  Consider deleting your other question with the same subject

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you have a typo in your XAML, it should read -

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
        <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding GetCommand, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Try the code after removing the `Mode=OneWay` from the binding expression.

HTH, indyfromoz